# Install ASP Classic components in Azure Web App

Tags: azure, asp-classic, azure-web-app-service

I am migrating an big set of old applications from Locaweb server to Microsoft Azure Web Apps. But, there are some ASP Classic applications which uses some server components like SoftArtisans.FileUp and SoftArtisans.SMTPMail.

Is there any chance to install these components in Azure Web Apps?

Answer (score 1):

You can't install and register COM components in Azure Web App.  You need to use a Virtual Machine to do so.

Answer (score 1):

[Azure WebApp is a sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox). As CSharpRocks mentioned that we can't install and register COM components in Azure WebApp.

> The sandbox generally aims to restrict access to shared components of Windows. Unfortunately, many core components of Windows have been designed as shared components: the registry, cryptography, and graphics subsystems, among others. This section outlines the limitations placed on usage of these often essential, yet shared components.